# Не могу получить дата-атрибут

Tags: javascript, attr

[image]

Не могу получить дата-атрибут.
Вывел то, что выходит в консоль. Однако в коде выходит то же самое при попытке вывести его console.log
Что странно если вывести сам тег, то в нем нормально показывается этот атрибут. Помогите, пожалуйста, заранее спасибо

Сниппет:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.url').getAttribute('url'))
```

```html
<div class="url" data-url="http://urist.kg/"></div>
```

Comment: `el.dataset.url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"da**r**a-url"? >> `data-url`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".url").dataset.url);
console.log(document.querySelector(".url").getAttribute("data-url"));
```

```html
<div class="url" data-url="http://urist.kg"></div>
```

Comment: Боже, храни тебя господь! Я два часа мучаюсь. БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @emirlan1 На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

[`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) ищет атрибут полностью соответствующий переданному параметру. В данном случае: `url`.

В разметке видно, что данного атрибута действительно нет, есть атрибут `data-url`.

Поэтому решением может стать изменение искомого атрибута:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.url').getAttribute('data-url'))
```

```html
<div class="url" data-url="http://urist.kg/"></div>
```

---

Альтернативным решением будет использование свойства [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), которое позволяет осуществлять доступ ко всем `data-` атрибутам элемента.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.url').dataset.url)
```

```html
<div class="url" data-url="http://urist.kg/"></div>
```

---

И еще одним решением будет изменение самой разметки:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.url').getAttribute('url'))
```

```html
<div class="url" url="http://urist.kg/"></div>
```